# Read 7-zip without extracting to files

Tags: c#, stream, 7zip

I have a 7-zip archive with a number of text files. I'd like to read the content of those text files without having to extract them onto the file system.

Is it possible to do it all in-memory?

Answer (score 1):

Install the NuGet package called `SevenZipSharp.Interop`

You can then read the files that are inside the archive:

```
static void ReadFilesInArchive(string archiveFilename)
{
    SevenZipBase.SetLibraryPath(@".\x86\7z.dll");
    var extractor = new SevenZipExtractor(archiveFilename);

    var filesInArchive = extractor.ArchiveFileData.ToList();

    filesInArchive.ForEach(f =>
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            extractor.ExtractFile(f.FileName, ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
            {
                var lines = sr.ReadAllLines();
                Console.WriteLine(lines.Count());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note that this relies on the following extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllLines(this StreamReader reader)
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}
```